# How to pass vector to integrate function

Tags: r

I want to integrate a function `fun_integrate` that has a vector `vec` as an input parameter:

```
fun_integrate <- function(x, vec) { 
  y <- sum(x > vec)
  dnorm(x) + y
}

#Works like a charm
fun_integrate(0, rnorm(100))

integrate(fun_integrate, upper = 3, lower = -3, vec = rnorm(100))
300.9973 with absolute error < 9.3e-07
Warning message:
  In x > vec :
  longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length
```

As far as I can see, the problem is the following: `integrate` calls `fun_integrate` for a vector of `x` that it computes based on `upper` and `lower`. This vectorized call seems not to work with another vector being passed as an additional argument. What I want is that `integrate` calls `fun_integrate` for each `x` that it computes internally and compares that single `x` to the vector `vec` and I'm pretty sure my above code doesn't do that.

I know that I could implement an integration routine myself, i.e. compute nodes between `lower` and `upper` and evaluate the function on each node separately. But that wouldn't be my preferred solution.

Also note that I checked `Vectorize`, but this seems to apply to a different problem, namely that the function doesn't accept a vector for `x`. My problem is that I want an additional vector as an argument.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
integrate(Vectorize(fun_integrate,vectorize.args='x'), upper = 3, lower = -3, vec = rnorm(100),subdivisions=10000)

304.2768 with absolute error < 0.013


#testing with an easier function
test<-function(x,y) {
  sum(x-y)
}

test(1,c(0,0))
[1] 2

test(1:5,c(0,0))
[1] 15
Warning message:
In x - y : 
longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length

Vectorize(test,vectorize.args='x')(1:5,c(0,0))
[1]  2  4  6  8 10

#with y=c(0,0) this is f(x)=2x and the integral easy to solve
integrate(Vectorize(test,vectorize.args='x'),1,2,y=c(0,0))
3 with absolute error < 3.3e-14 #which is correct
```

Comment: I was going to say: Good point.  Maybe one of us should write a quick trapezoidal version and see if the answer is closer to 300 or 6400   But you went and changed everything!  :-) .  Did you do something like that to verify this version integrates properly?

Comment: So Vectorize was indeed the answer...so much for having checked that from my side ;-) Anyways, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

Roland's answer looks good.  Just wanted to point out that it's `sum` , not `integrate` that is throwing the warning message.

```
Rgames> xf <- 1:10
Rgames> vf <- 4:20
Rgames> sum(xf>vf)
[1] 0
Warning message:
In xf > vf :
 longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length
```

The fact that the answer you got is not the correct value is what suggests that `integrate` is not sending the x-vector you expected to your function.