# Pass two or more vectors to integrate function

Tags: r, vector, integrate

I was trying to integrate this function in which k1 & m1 are two input vectors

```
k_z <- function(z, k1, m1) {
  k_z <- k1 * exp(-z / m1)
}
```

I adapted the solution from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12058405/how-to-pass-vector-to-integrate-function)

```
integrate(Vectorize(k_z, vectorize.args = "z"), upper = 2, lower = 0, k1 = rnorm(10), m1 = rnorm(10))
```

but got the following error

```
Error in integrate(Vectorize(k_z, vectorize.args = "z"), upper = 2, lower = 0,  : 
  evaluation of function gave a result of wrong length
```

I have tried many different ways to no avail. What did I do wrong? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your function k_z is not a scalar point '*function*', since it does not return a single value given a single set of values of the arguments as needed by the integration function (since it's 1-to-many): let k_z return a single value like the following, it will work:

```
k_z <- function(z, k1, m1) {
  sum(k1 * exp(-z / m1)) # return a single value, not a vector of multiple values
}

k_z_vec <- Vectorize(k_z, vectorize.args = "z")
integrate(k_z_vec, upper = 2, lower = 0, k1 = rnorm(10), m1 = rnorm(10))
# -7.338221e+14 with absolute error < 1.4e+07
```

If you want to compute multiple integrations with different values from the 
 vectors k1 and m1, you may try the following:

```
k_z <- function(z, k1, m1) {
  k1 * exp(-z / m1)
}
k1 <- rnorm(10)
m1 <- rnorm(10)
sapply(1:10, function(x) integrate(k_z, upper = 3, lower = -3, k1=k1[x], m1=m1[x]))

            [,1]         [,2]         [,3]         [,4]         [,5]       [,6]         [,7]         [,8]         [,9]         [,10]       
value        -21.4522     4.330284e+40 19.4474      3.900487e+21 9649111978 2.092415e+57 -34.86148    10103.57     -8.232609    46.35694    
abs.error    2.381672e-13 2.705507e+35 2.159095e-13 1.129735e+17 83251.15   1.180714e+49 3.870402e-13 0.0003484398 9.140032e-14 5.942846e-10
subdivisions 1            4            1            3            2          5            1            1            1            1           
message      "OK"         "OK"         "OK"         "OK"         "OK"       "OK"         "OK"         "OK"         "OK"         "OK"        
call         Expression   Expression   Expression   Expression   Expression Expression   Expression   Expression   Expression   Expression
```